# jQuery serialize() doesn't serializes with jQuery Validate captcha

Tags: jquery, serialization, jquery-validate

It seems simple but I can't get a solution. serialize() doesn't get any form values. console.log(data) retrieves empty text in console.

**Form**

```
    <form id="form-contact" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="#" role="form">
            <fieldset class="col-xs-5">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstname">First name <span>*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" />
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="captcha">Insert captcha... <span>*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="captcha" name="captcha" />
        </div>

     .....

            </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**Script**

```
var formContact = $("#form-contact");

function sendContactEmail() {

    var data = formContact.serialize();

    console.log(data); // Output: (empty)

    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data + '&action=sendcontactmail',
        cache: false,

        success: function (html) {
          ...
        },
    error: function() {
          ...
    }
    });

}


/* 
 * Validation Form with jquery.validate plugin
 */
formContact.validate({
    rules:{
      ...
   'captcha':{
    required: true,
    number: true,
    remote: urlCaptcha  // If I comment this line all works
    }
      ...
    }, //rules

    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false,

    submitHandler: function() {
        sendContactEmail();
    }

}); // end Validate
```

**Instead this works**:

```
$("footer").click(function() {
    var dataform = formContact.serialize();
    console.log(dataform); // Output: OK, all the form values are here
});
```

**EDIT**:

Maybe I found where's the issue. It seems to be releated to jquery-validate rules. I've a rule for a captcha input in the form. If I comment the line `remote: urlCaptcha` all works, but I obviously need that line to check the captcha.

**Rule**

```
'captcha':{
    required: true,
    number: true,
    remote: urlCaptcha
    }
```

**urlCaptcha** is defined in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var urlCaptcha = 'http://localhost/project/wp-content/themes/my_theme/assets/js/plugins/captcha/process.php';</script>
```

Comment: Do `console.log(formContact)` right before you log the data to make sure it's not a scoping issue of the `formContact` variable.

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D3LLZ/1/

Comment: console.log(formContact) --> [object Object] and console.log(data) --> undefined

Comment: here doesn't work... some ideas? look at the add on the bottom of first post

Comment: I found something wrong, please check the Edit